# How to get a title of public video item on Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

Currently I am using this url to get a public video's info:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID
?callback=
&method=GET
&metadata=false
&format=json
&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But I'm having trouble with getting a valid access token.
Tried Facebook PHP SDK but no success.
So, I'm looking for an easier way to get video's title.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I've AppId & AppSecret.

Comment: You mentioned you've used the SDK but How are you grabbing the data in this example? CURL, file_get_contents or the PHP SDK?

Comment: @David Barker: at the moment I use file_get_contents and it works if I manually insert any valid access_token in the url above. I've tried PHP SDK to get desired access_token, but I got a short access_token instead. I'll use cURL if it helps.

Comment: I don't think cURL is the way forward here as it is without doubt the more complex option to use when working with FB apps. You must make sure that your user is authorised for your app with the `user_videos` permission. When an FB dialog redirects it issues a signed_request on your apps main page. Now, If you use the PHP SDK : `$access = $facebook->getAccessToken();` will contain a valid access token as long as the above condition is true.

Comment: @David Barker: How to get access token with user_videos permission? Could you provide some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually signed up to facebook and used their api to get a valid access token?

Comment: At the moment I manually get a valid access token on Graph API Explorer page.

Answer (score 0):

@Ken in response to comments, this is similar to the code I use on tab pages that link to my apps. This link will request permissions and then redirect to the app. As it is redirected from a dialog a signed_request is issued.

tab page:

```
<?PHP
$config = array('appId' = 'YOUR_APP_ID', 'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET');

$fbcanvas = "https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE/";
$scope = "user_video";

$oauth = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $config['appId'] .
         "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($fbcanvas) . 
         "&scope=" . $scope;
?>

<a href="<?PHP echo $oauth; ?>">Click here to authorise my application</a>
```

application page: (make sure to include FB's PHP SDK)

```
$config = array('appId' = 'YOUR_APP_ID', 'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET');

$fb = new Facebook($config);
$access = $fb->getAccessToken();

...
```

$access will now hold your valid Access Token. It is saved as a $_SESSION variable by the SDK (the SDK also starts a session if one is not already active).

```
var_dump ($_SESSION); // will give you all the info that the SDK
                      // has saved into $_SESSION
```

Now your user is authed you can utilise the permissions you've asked for, in this case you can make graph API calls through the SDK or file_get_contents.

```
$vids = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID" .
                          "?callback=" .
                          "&method=GET" .
                          "&metadata=false" .
                          "&format=json" .
                          "&access_token=" . $access);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To make things clear. I am creating a web app running on my web server. I've a simple html form on my web site, user enters a FB video url and clicks submit button. So, my script should fetch the video's info from FB & record that info into my MySQL DB. I don't want my visitors see any FB dialogs, etc. Is it possible? Thanks in advice.

Comment: No, you must auth your user to allow your app, as an untrusted third party, to gain any information about a user other than info they make public. This in most cases is first name, last name and Facebook ID. It's worth reading up on the videos section of the graph api, an access token must be supplied,  the examples FB give require a user access token so Auth is 100% required.